# XSLT calling template based on the condition

Tags: xslt

I have a problem in my real-time XSLT files. Based on that, i am putting my question here. I have 3 xslt files such as 1.xsl and master.xsl. This master.xsl is imported into 1.xsl

On the master.xsl, i am using this below code

```
<xsl:call-template name="content">
<xsl:with-param name="request" select="$request"/>
<xsl:call-template>
```

Like wise, on the 1.xsl,

```
<xsl:template name="content">
<xsl:param name="request" as="node()"/>
....
</xsl:template>
```

In this case, on the file 1.xsl, some time, for the template 'content', the `parameter` request, there wont be passed. it will be passed in some time.

so, the above template will be(without parameter 'request') in some cases

```
<xsl:template name="content">

    ....
</xsl:template>
```

when there is no parameter, this is showing error as of now

`XTSE0680: Parameter request is not declared in the called template`

so, in this case, kindly give me some ideas to modify the coding on `master.xsl`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092393/xslt-calling-template-with-xslwith-param-on-different-template

Comment: @markdark, it seems same but this is different. I asked another questions with same code. any ideas? pls

Comment: what 'as' is mean ? in as="node()"

Comment: It is a parameter to pass with set of xml tags

Comment: You may pass dummy element if 'Content' parameter does not exist by xsl:choose element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optional parameters when calling an XSL template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830780/optional-parameters-when-calling-an-xsl-template)

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for the error message have been pointed out in the answer to [XSLT calling template with xsl:with-param on different template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092393/xslt-calling-template-with-xslwith-param-on-different-template). You have to modify the template to declare the parameter. Or you would need to change the code in `master.xsl` to only pass the parameter with e.g.

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$request">
     <xsl:call-template name="content">
       <xsl:with-param name="request" select="$request"/>
     <xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:call-template name="content"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

That will only pass in `$request` if it is a non-empty sequence. Of course if your code is included in a stylesheet where the template does declare the parameter and the variable `$request` is not empty you will continue to experience the error. There is no way to check at run-time whether the template expects a param or not.

Comment: a / was missing to close the 1st <xsl:call-template>